# PHP Variable not working the way I am sure it worked before

Tags: php

Hi there I hope someone can help me

I have this variable

```
var $page_slug = "posts";
```

and want to make insert a dynamic value into the "posts" section but for some reason I keep getting an error that the code is not formatted correctly?

```
var $page_slug = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Above cause error... (With the formatting)...
I have also tried

```
var $page_slug = ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].";
```

I still get an error?

I cannot see why I cannot get to make the value dynamic, would appreciate any help!

This is part of the code:

```
class FakePage
{
var $page_slug = "author/admin/posts";
    /**
     * The slug for the fake post.  This is the URL for your plugin, like:
     * http://site.com/about-me or http://site.com/?page_id=about-me
     * @var string
     */

    /**
     * The title for your fake post.
     * @var string
     */
var $page_title = "Test";
```

as soon as I do

```
class FakePage
    {
```

$page_slug = ""; <--- with a dynamic value it gives me an error...

Comment: `var`?? never seen it in `PHP`

Comment: You can't assign anything but literals to class properties. Do, what you're trying to do, in the class constructor. @Салман http://www.php.net/manual/language.oop5.visibility.php search for 'var'.

Comment: `var` in PHP is a throwback to PHP4, you should be using PHP5 now; or are you confusing PHP and javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using it in a class like:

```
class Test {
    var $page_slug = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

This is not possible, make sure you set it in the constructor (or another) method

```
class Test {
    public $page_slug;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->page_slug = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`var` in PHP4 can be used only in classes. As of PHP5 it's deprecated.

Simply remove the `var` and it should work.